# Java EE 6 Framework

Tags: java, java-ee-6

GWT Framework, Spring framework, Play Framework, Seam framework were used to create a MVC style framework for Java.

I've been searching online for the past 3 days to find if a framework should be used for Java EE 6 but I'm having a hard time finding the right answer.

This article here says that frameworks are not needed in Java EE 6 anymore:

> [Moving from Spring to Java EE 6: The Age of Frameworks is Over](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=61023)

I read this post:

> [Do I need frameworks to complement a Java EE 6, JSF-2 Web-App? Which ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051077/do-i-need-frameworks-to-complement-a-java-ee-6-jsf-2-web-app-which-ones)

But I still don't get the answer of what framework to use ?

Is a framework really required? If not, is there a diagram that will show equivalent Java EE 6 frameworkworks ?

Is JSF a framework ?

Comment: 1) `But I still don't get the answer of what framework to use?` This is unanswerable. You'll need to evaluate frameworks yourself and pick the one you feel more comfortable with. 2) `Is a framework really required` [When NOT to use a framework](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49488/when-not-to-use-a-framework) & [Need for a framework](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/52961/need-for-a-framework) 3) `is there a diagram` Search for "Java EE 6 framework comparison" 4) `Is JSF a framework?` [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces)

Comment: To expand a bit on point 1: I'm currently using about ten different frameworks on a 2*10^6 loc project. I'm only using a bit from each, the good parts (good here means works as advertised, and wasn't interested in writing it myself). About a third of the codebase though, doesn't really use any framework (although parts of it could be called an in-house framework). Use what you need _and_ what works, mix and match if appropriate, and don't lose too much sleep over a couple of blogposts.

Comment: Thanks tannis, the places I worked for previously used Java 5 and used Spring heavily. I've recently been on Java 6 project and thats why I was confused if I should be using a spring framework or not. I've decided to just use JSF, Primefaces, Jersey RestFul web service, JPA to build the application. Seems like that's all I need for now. But I'm not sure if I should be using EJBs. Is transaction handling easier with EJB's ? or I should be ok just using servlets with POJO's ? I'm trying to build a Java ecommerce website.

Comment: `Is transaction handling easier with EJB's` I have no idea, sorry ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start with a big NO. You do not need any framework to create a web application.

Now, when we see the current state of enterprise web applications. There are widely accepted standards/patterns. These standards will help you in creating a modular infrastructure.

Before deciding on the framework. Before looking into what to use or what to avoid, just ask few questions to yourself.

- What is your problem domain?
- What is the scope of your web applications?
- Who is going to maintain the application in long run?

A framework will provide you an infrastructure to design over. If I talk about the `Spring` Framework, it will provide MVC infrastructure. Along with this, it will also support you in other aspects of your application. For example, it will manage your container and all the application's modules through its own IOC container. When you need some aspect implementation, it will give you AOP layer to implement your aspect. This framework will be ready to give you out of the box transaction management when your needs grow. It will also provide a good abstracted database layer. There are many more.

So, define your needs. Find the solution. Once your needs are defined, you can explore the ability/<> of the frameworks.

Yes, JSF is a framework. It is used to create UI design. This is a java based framework and provides AJAX like solution for web applications.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply. I will be using Java ee 6 so I guess I don't need to use frameworks. I will just go with primefaces and Java ee 6 like rkosegi said in the post. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

Look, you need framework for UI component set like richfaces, primefaces, etc.

REST, EJB, JPA , JSF - all these technologies are part of JavaEE 6 specification and all application servers must implement them if they are EE6 certified.

Answer (score 2):

> - Can you someone please recommend me a really good framework for an website which will use Ajax, EJB-3.1, RESTFul web service, MySQL?

I think you should have a look at [Spring Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), which should satisfy your needs.

> - Or is a framework really required ? If not, then is there a diagram that will show how Java EE 6 framework works ?

For basic website stuff, I don't think you need to use framework. But as soon as you start scaling it, it becomes easier to scale if you use frameworks. I have a very good experience of this with Spring.
For Java EE6 overview, please read [this](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363662/Java-EE-6-Overview).

> - Is JSF a framework ?

Yes, [Java Server Faces (JSF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) is indeed a framework majorly used for integration of web-based user interfaces.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply. I'm using Java EE 6. I've used Spring before and understand how it work but I read that Java ee 6 does not need frameworks anymore. So just wanted to confirm that. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry if I missed it in my reply, but Java EE 6 itself is a framework (which includes JSP, Servlet, EJB, etc.)
Also, if you think this is good / right answer, please don't forget to upvote / mark as answer. :)